# how to sum numbers from two different text files in python

Tags: python

So, i have this problem:

i have three txt-files: number1.txt, number2.txt and number3.txt.

number1.txt have this number: 10 and number2.txt have this number too.

So, what i want to do, is to sum up these numbers and add result to number3.txt.

I have already this code:

```
number1 = open("files/number1.txt", encoding="utf-8").read()
number2 = open("files/number2.txt", encoding="utf-8").read()
number3 = open("files/number3.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
result = float(number1) + float(number2)
number3.write(str(result))
```

But nothing shows up on the number3.txt. I have no idea why this is not working. I know this is maybe an pretty stupid question, but i hope you guys can help me.

I have python 3.4.3.

Comment: Have you tried `print(result)`?

Comment: Yes, and python printed the right result, but nothing still doesn't appear on number3.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't closed or flushed the file.
Make sure you have a `number3.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to always close your files, and the way you're doing it all of them remain open. In order to do that, use the `with` command:

```
with open("files/number1.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
  number1 = f.read()
with open("files/number2.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
  number2 = f.read()
result = float(number1) + float(number2)
with open("files/number3.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
  f.write(result)
```

That way you don't have to worry about closing your files, since they get closed automatically.